# Whats the point of ViewStub when I can also lazily inflate a view without it?

Tags: android

After reading the docs, I'm not sure what ViewStub accomplish that I cannot with creating a XML with a View and then inflating it at run time.

The Doc says use ViewStub to inflate views at run time.  I'm not sure why this is useful other than syntax is a little easier.

Or am I totally wrong about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic use of `ViewStub` is to act as a "placeholder" to an element that won't be needed at a later time without taking additional upfront performance load. Now, your question why not just inflate it dynamically then?

They serve both purposes the same, only that when using a `ViewStub`, you separate and already define the all of your UI in a separate XML, so it's a separation of concerns. Now if you've got a dynamic UI, then it would be better to go programmatically inflating your UI.

So all in all,

- defined UI: prefer `ViewStub`
- dynamic UI: prefer programmatically inflating `Views`

As for my experience, I've used it for a project I've had to maintain and needed to overcome a complex hierarchy of `Views`, which took too long to load. `ViewStub` helped in lazy loading a defined UI, improving the start-up of the UI.

Comment: You think I should use ViewStubs to display a Progress Spinner?  Or is it bad practice?

Comment: If the `ProgressBar` is a defined UI on the screen, then it's okay to go with `ViewStub`. However, it would be much better to go set your 'ProgressBar' to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` initially on your layout, as using a `ViewStub` in this scenario won't have any significant impact on the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say that you have some chunk of the screen that's supposed to be one of 3 different UIs, but you won't know which until runtime.  You can use a ViewStub and inflate the correct one at runtime.  And because the ViewStub is in there, it won't force a relayout of your screen, because you already reserved space for it.  Yes, this sounds a little bit like a fragment, but this existed before fragments, and its lighter weight than coding a fragment.  It can also be used recursively in a way Fragments would have a difficult time doing-  for example a tree based structure could have a ViewStub that you could inflate for non-leaf nodes but leave as is for leaf nodes.

Its not something you should be using frequently, but it does have some uses.

Comment: Thats a good answer.  I'm thinking of using this for showing a progress Spinner.  In the middle of the screen before the content gets loaded.  You think ViewStub is a good thing to use here then?

Comment: I'd go with @deubaka's answer from below-  its probably better to just use the visibility to hide and display it for something that simple.